# Wheat brought from the Diaspora to Israel: biblical or rabbinic challah-obligation?

Tags: rambam, chutz-laaretz, maaser-tithes, separating-challah, maseches-challa

[Challah 2:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Challah.2.1?lang=bi):

> פֵּרוֹת חוּצָה לָאָרֶץ שֶׁנִּכְנְסוּ לָאָרֶץ, חַיָּבִים בַּחַלָּה.‏
>
> Produce [grown] outside the land [of Israel] that came into the land is subject to *challah*.

What is the nature of this obligation? Is it biblical or rabbinic?

The motivation for asking this question is [Rambam Hilchot Terumot 1:22](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Heave_Offerings.1.22?lang=bi):

> פֵּרוֹת חוּצָה לָאָרֶץ שֶׁנִּכְנְסוּ לָאָרֶץ חַיָּבִין בְּחַלָּה שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר שָׁמָּה. שָׁמָּה אַתֶּם חַיָּבִין בֵּין בְּפֵרוֹת הָאָרֶץ בֵּין בְּפֵרוֹת חוּצָה לָאָרֶץ. וְאִם נִקְבְּעוּ לְמַעֲשֵׂר בְּיַד יִשְׂרָאֵל אַחַר שֶׁנִּכְנְסוּ לָאָרֶץ חַיָּבִין בְּמַעַשְׂרוֹת מִדִּבְרֵיהֶם:‏
>
> Produce [grown] outside the land [of Israel] that came into the land is subject to *challah*, as it is written "there". 'There' you are obligated, whether the produce is [grown] in the land or outside the land. And if it became obligated in *ma'aser* through the actions of a Jew after it came into the land, it is subject to *ma'aser* rabbinically.

One could infer from the words of Rambam that the obligation of *ma'aser* on produce grown in the Diaspora and completed in Israel is rabbinic, as opposed to *challah* which would be a biblical obligation in this case.

Is this a valid inference? If so, what is the reason to differentiate between *challah* and *ma'aser*?

Comment: Remember Challah is also taken from wheat grown by non Jews if it was owned by Jews when kneaded. That should point you in the right direction

Comment: @DoubleAA As opposed to ma’aser from produce grown by non-Jews purchased prior to *meiruach*?

Answer (score 1):

Footnotes 92 and 93 to [Rambam Hilchos Terumah 1:22](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/992027/jewish/Terumot-Chapter-1.htm) explain the halacha. Note that the difference is based on what is involved in the completion of the work.

> **22** When produce from Eretz Yisrael is taken to the Diaspora, it is exempt from the obligations of challah, the terumot, and the tithes,
>   [for one of the prooftexts requiring the separation of these gifts,
>   Numbers 15:18]91states: "[the land] to which I am bringing you."
>   [Implied is that] these obligations exist there alone. In the
>   Diaspora, one is exempt.<sup>92</sup> If [the produce] was taken to
>   Syria, one is obligated by Rabbinic decree.
>
> Conversely, we are obligated [to separate] challah from produce from
>   the Diaspora that was brought into Eretz Yisrael, as [suggested by the
>   phrase] "to which." [Implied is that] one is liable [to make these
>   gifts] there, whether the produce is from Eretz Yisrael or the
>   Diaspora. If the obligation [to separate challah or the tithes] was
>   established [because of the actions] of a Jew after the produce
>   entered Eretz Yisrael, there is an obligation of Rabbinic origin to
>   separate the tithes.<sup>93</sup>
>
> <sup>92.</sup> The Ra'avad differs and maintains that the exemption
>   from the obligation to tithe applies only according to Scriptural Law.
>   According to Rabbinic Law, all authorities agree that one is
>   obligated, for this produce is comparable to that of Ammon and Moav.
>   The Radbaz does not accept this perspective, stating that there is no
>   source which maintains that a Rabbinic obligation exists. The Radbaz
>   does, however, qualify the Rambam's ruling, explaining that it applies
>   only when the work that makes the produce obligated to be tithed is
>   completed in the Diaspora. If this work is completed in Eretz Yisrael,
>   the obligation to separate the tithes has already been incurred and
>   they must be separated even if the produce was later taken to the
>   Diaspora. For this reason, in most instances, terumah and tithes must
>   be separated from produce that is grown in Eretz Yisrael in the
>   present age and later exported to the Diaspora. This, however, applies
>   to fruits only, not vegetables as stated in Chapter 2, Halachah 6.
>
> <sup>93.</sup> The Kessef Mishneh questions why the obligation to
>   separate the tithes is only of Rabbinic origin. Since the concept is
>   based on the exegesis of the same Biblical term as mentioned above, if
>   the work that made the produce obligated to be tithed was performed in
>   Eretz Yisrael, why is the obligation not Scriptural in origin? The
>   Kessef Mishneh answers that since the prooftext mentions "the bread of
>   the land," one can conclude that the obligation applies only to
>   produce grown in the Holy Land itself. Alternatively, the Kessef
>   Mishneh suggests that indeed if the work that makes the produce
>   obligated to be tithed is completed only in Eretz Yisrael, the
>   obligation is indeed Scriptural in origin. This ruling is quoted by
>   the Siftei Cohen 331:22.

Comment: Looking up the Kesef Mishnah quoted in your footnote 93 inside, it seems like his question is based on the inference I presented, but his two answers actually say that *challah* and *ma'aser* essentially have the same rule.

Comment: And his two approaches differ as to whether produce brought into Israel before kneading is biblically or rabinically subject to *challah*.